# Web Scraping - Every scroll the data changes and only 20 entries are showed

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to web scrape this web site, but the pages content changes when scroll and only 20 entries are shown.

As shown my code below, it only gives 20 enteries and if I scroll down before running the code, the 20 entries change.

I want to get the whole 896 entries all at once.

```
main = requests.get("https://www.sarbanes-oxley-forum.com/category/20/general-sarbanes-oxley-   discussion/21")
soup = BeautifulSoup(main.content,"lxml")
main_dump = soup.find_all("h2",{"class":"title","component":{"topic/header"}})
for k in range(len(main_dump)):
    main_titles.append(main_dump[k].find("a").text)
    main_links.append("https://www.sarbanes-oxley-forum.com/"+main_dump[k].find("a").attrs["href"])

print(len(main_links))
```

Output: `20`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `BeautifulSoup` nor `selenium` in this case, cause you could get all data structured from their api. Simply request the first page, check the number of topics and iterate over:

```
https://www.sarbanes-oxley-forum.com/api/category/20/general-sarbanes-oxley-discussion/1
```

##### Example

*Note*: Replace `894` with `1` to start over from first page, I just limited the number of requests for demo here starting from page `894`:

```
import requests

api_url = 'https://www.sarbanes-oxley-forum.com/api/category/20/general-sarbanes-oxley-discussion/'
data = []
for i in range(894,requests.get(api_url+'1').json()['totalTopicCount']+1):
    for e in requests.get(api_url+str(i)).json()['topics']:
        data.append({
            'title':e['title'],
            'url': 'https://www.sarbanes-oxley-forum.com/topic/'+e['slug']
        })
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'We have a team of expert',
  'url': 'https://www.sarbanes-oxley-forum.com/topic/8550/we-have-a-team-of-expert'},
 {'title': 'What is the privacy in Google Nest Wifi?',
  'url': 'https://www.sarbanes-oxley-forum.com/topic/8552/what-is-the-privacy-in-google-nest-wifi'},
 {'title': 'Reporting Requirements _and_amp; Financial Results Release Timin  382',
  'url': 'https://www.sarbanes-oxley-forum.com/topic/6214/reporting-requirements-_and_amp-financial-results-release-timin-382'},
 {'title': 'Use of digital signatures instead of wet ink signatures on control documentation',
  'url': 'https://www.sarbanes-oxley-forum.com/topic/8476/use-of-digital-signatures-instead-of-wet-ink-signatures-on-control-documentation'},...]
```